# How does hex address range equal to a size in bytes?

Tags: hex, memory-address

Suppose I have an arbitrary hexadecimal range, for the purposes of this example

```
address_low = 0x0800_0000

address_high = 0x0FFF_FFFF
```

Each address is is a 32-bit, or 4-byte, word ("32 address bits"). The total number of locations in the range is

```
address_high-address_low + 1 = 0x8000000
```

equivalently: decimal 134217728, or 128*(1024*1024), or 2^27.

What I am confused about is what it means to represent this range as a number of bytes, specifically 128 MiB. To me, the hex address range simply specifies how many registers can be pointed to (specifically, 2^27). But each place that can be pointed to could have anything in it. Maybe just one bit, maybe a gigabyte.

So referring to an address range in terms of bytes without specifying what each address points to just doesn't make any sense to me. Am I missing something here? Can anyone help me understand why the byte expression of a hex address range makes sense?

Thank you. Happy to try to clarify anything I've said on request.

Comment: One might think of addresses as Mailboxes on a continuous street (no gaps, increment by one), each with a single byte.  CPU instructions reference that address, and also have a length indicator to get/put 1 byte, 2 bytes, 4bytes, 8 bytes, or for some repetative instructions a "length" of bytes one at a time..  The Lo/Hi address may be loaded into system level permission registers, so that user app instructions must be within, or get memory errors when outside the range.

Comment: Could you clarify or emphasize how that answers the question? I want to be sure of my interpretation of your response.

Comment: The Address does not point to a register, just to a single byte.  A range of addresses point to a series of individual bytes.  Please clarify your question further if this is not enuf